# changing activity using buttons inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have seen tutorials about fragments where a main activity is created with buttons for changing fragment after fragment. my question is, can i change fragments using the button of the called layout instead of the main activity's button/s. that is my current dilemma. before, my app runs using intent to change activities. but i came across a problem where i need to use fragment to solve it.

here is my "main" fragment code:

```
public class FragmentMain extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_main);
        Log.d("Batelec", "fragment main started");
    }

    public void selectFrag(View view) {
         Fragment fr;

         fr = new FragmentMain2();
         FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fr);
         fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}
```

here's my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mypower_build101.FragmentMain" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.example.mypower_build101.FragmentMain2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's my main activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddDevice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/txtAddDevice"
        android:onClick="addClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShowDevice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAddDevice"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/txtShowDevice"
        android:onClick="showClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMainRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnShowDevice"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/txtRegister"
        android:onClick="registerClick" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShowDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnMainRegister"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:text="@string/txtShowDialog" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnShowDialog"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/listViewPadding"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/txtNull"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchGCM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="@string/txtConnect2GCM"
        android:textOff="@string/txtNo"
        android:textOn="@string/txtYes" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBroadCastMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblStatus"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lblStatus"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblStatus"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/txtNull"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

if i really need to create buttons outside my already functioning activity, can you give some tips on how to properly code them i've seen that using static is not the best way to do it. also give me some tips on how to place the new button in the fragment because my main activity has 4 buttons which already used for changing activities.
all help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you want to do is best to use fragments that programmatically additions on the activity.

I'll leave a small project where I have about an activity, and using two buttons, one fragment screen replacement by another.

You can find the complete code in the link that sends Gitub and you can download if you want is free for you to use and analyze as you wish.

[Fragmetn replaces another Fragment. Github Project](https://github.com/danielorozco06/FragmentReplace)

And I leave the screenshot so you can see how it works.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

I hope that my help has been very useful.

Comment: hey i tried to do what i want based on the image i uploaded here. what happened is that the fragmented activity show but it shows at the top of the mainactivity. it seems that fragments are transparent activities. can you  teach me how can i hide the main activity. also the clickable items on the activity shown inside the fragment loses its functionality like how my spinner can't put text on the edit texts anymore.

Answer (score 0):

so you mean, i still need to have a separate button for changing activities and i can't anymore use my previous buttons. i just thought, can i use my previous main activity then call an activity which contain a fragment. when i click a button the main activity, the button calls the "fragmented" activity and change the fragment it calls

[like this sorry the say i am not allowed to put image here yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiIYu.jpg)